# how to get the indexvalue for given option in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box with various options which are loaded dynamically . I am writing code to  iterate through the code and make it the default option if the text value is a particular value example for in this case 8065992445. Not getting a way to do it.

```
$("#locationselect > option").each(function() {
          if(this.text==8065992445)

        });
```

Comment: The option's value or the text (could be the same)??? Your question is quite unclear but maybe you just want to set select value: `$("#locationselect').val(8065992445);`. Or `$("#locationselect > option[value='8065992445']").prop('selected', true);`

Comment: Note: `8065992445` is NOT an integer value (32 bit)! The max. integer value is `2147483647`

Comment: @abhishek Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val) method to get the value of select option:

```
$("#locationselect > option").each(function() {
    if($(this).val()==8065992445){
      //do your task...
    }
});
```

Comment: option value could be different than option displayed text. It is not clear what OP is expecting

Comment: As per OP statement: `Not getting a way to do it.` I think this is what OP is looking for. Otherwise code would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check value of `option` use `$(selector).val()` to getting value of option.

```js
$("option").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "3")
        $(this).text($(this).text() + " - Changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

And if you want to check text of `option` use `$(selector).text()` to getting text of option.

```js
$("option").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == "Option 2")
        $(this).text($(this).text() + " - Changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```